# Error component route is rendering below every other component route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In my code below the `Error` page is rendering together with every other component.
I would like the `Error` page to render only when the url is wrongly typed and another component cannot be rendered:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Navbar, Sidebar, Footer } from "./components";
import {
  Home,
  SingleProduct,
  Cart,
  Checkout,
  Error,
  About,
  Products,
  PrivateRoute,
} from "./pages";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Sidebar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/about" element={<About />} />
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="products">
          <Route index element={<Products />} />
          <Route exact path=":productId" element={<SingleProduct />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
      </Routes>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am expecting the error page to load on wrongly typed URLs and it's working, but it also renders in every single url below my other components.

Comment: You don't need to write  `<Routes>` for every `<Route>`. All `<Route>`  should be part of one `<Routes>` component.

Comment: have you tried moving your error route to the top to all other routes?

Comment: Why was this post closed for needing debugging details? The issue with the code is explained, and a relevant code example was provided. This is answerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as any other route is matched and rendered within a single `Routes` component, the "catch-all" `Error` route and component won't be rendered.

Change your router to this:

```
<Router>
  <Navbar />
  <Sidebar />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="/cart" element={<Cart />} />
    <Route path="products">
      <Route index element={<Products />} />
      <Route path=":productId" element={<SingleProduct />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</Router>
```